# Unable to print multiple keys of different dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to print multiple keys from different dictionaries in a list. My dictionary turns out right with the correct items, but when I try to format the final print statement, it just prints the last input. It does not save the local variables.
And I am pretty lost with how to do the grand total too since that involves the local variables.

Here is my code:

```
#making the list
grocery_history = []

#assign grand total variable
grand_total = 0

#definition of the input sequence
def questions():

    #creating the individual dictionary for each item
    current_item = {}

    #assigning the item name keys
    print("Item name:")
    item_name = input()
    current_item['name'] = item_name

    #assigning the quantity keys
    print("Quantity purchased:")
    quantity = input()
    current_item['number'] = quantity

    #assigning the cost keys
    print("Price per item:")
    cost = input()
    current_item['price'] = cost

    #calculating the item total and assigning its' key
    item_total = float(quantity) * float(cost)
    current_item['item_total'] = item_total

    #input option to continue
    print("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:")
    choice = input()

    #adding dictionary to list
    grocery_history.append(current_item)

    #defining the final formating
    def final_string():
        print(str(current_item['number']) + " " + str(current_item['name']) +  " @   $" + str(current_item['price']) + " ea   $" + str(current_item["item_total"]))

    #option to continue
    if choice == "c":
        questions()

    #option to print summary
    elif choice == "q":
        #### I think this is where my problem is
        for i in range(len(grocery_history)):
            final_string()
        ## not sure if this is how to calculate grand total
        for x in range (len(grocery_history)):
            x = item_total
            grand_total = item_total + x

    print("Grand total: $" + str(grand_total))


#call questions function
questions()
```

Comment: Please put a sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function has to get the item it should print as a parameter. I used an f-string to format the output. That's much nicer than concatenating strings by hand.

```
def final_string(item):
    print(f"{item['number']} {item['name']} @   ${item['price']} ea   ${item['item_total']}")
```

BTW, the function `final_string` should be defined on top level, not in the function `questions`.

Now you have to add the parameter where you call the function.

```
for i in range(len(grocery_history)):
    final_string(grocery_history[i])
```

But using a range over the length of an iterable to access single elements isn't very pythonic and more complex than it has to be. An iterable (like a list) is ... iterable. So change this code to:

```
for item in grocery_history:
    final_string(item)
```

---

To calculate the grand total you have to add the total of each item. Since your item is a dictionary and the total of the item is the value of the entry with the key `'item_total'` you have to add those values.

```
grand_total = 0
for item in grocery_history:
    grand_total += item['item_total']
```

Or as a one liner using [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and a generator.

```
grand_total = sum(item['item_total'] for item in grocery_history)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to have a parameter for `final_string()`. Otherwise, it only going to print the value of current_item.

I'd pull out the final string function as follows

```
def final_string(item):
    print(str(item['number']) + " " + str(item['name']) +  " @   $" + str(item['price']) + " ea   $" + str(item["item_total"]))
```

Then change your code accordingly

```
#option to print summary
elif choice == "q":
    for item in grocery_history:
        final_string(item)
    grand_total = sum([item['item_total'] for item in grocery_history])
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this is a very bizarre way of writing this code. In fact, you may be making it harder for yourself than it actually needs to be.
I've redone it a much simpler way:

```
groceries = []

shopping = True

while shopping:
    item = {
        "Name":input("Name:\n"),
        "Quantity":float(input("Quantity:\n")),
        "PricePerItem":float(input("Price Per Item:\n"))
        }
    groceries.append(item)
    if "n" == input("Continue?(y/n) ").lower():
        shopping = False

total = 0
for item in groceries:
    total += item["Quantity"] * item["PricePerItem"]
    print(item["Name"]+" - Quantity: "+str(item["Quantity"])+" Price Per Item: $"+str(item["PricePerItem"])+" Current Total: $"+str(total)+"\n")

print("Grand Total: $"+str(total))
```

This will give you an output like this:
[image]

Comment: Of course one would respect the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and would call the variable `shopping` and not `Shopping`. And then one would think again, throw out this variable, run the loop as `while True:` and would use `break` to leave the loop.

Comment: Says the one that thought the above code was worth improving. I'll admit I should have named it "shopping" but in my opinion, using the variable to break out the loop is better practice as its easier to read.

Comment: Thank you so much!